How was fraud by false representation charged in this case?
https://www.casemine.com/judgement/uk/647a3c186976b07b5ff4d92e
In the above conviction and failed appeal the Defendant seemingly catfished the victim by pretending to be a modelling agency and various other personas. The victim sent nude images, was promised money for more and sent more and then instead of receiving money was blackmailed for further images at which point she went to the police.
The blackmail charge was admitted to as well as the fraud by false representation but only the fraud charge was used for the conviction.
In the appeal judgement attached I cannot find exactly why the fraud charge was selected as primarily this seems to be a blackmail attempt.
The judge says its an unusual fraud case as there was no express financial loss.
Being as fraud has to involve a financial or property loss or gain is this a strange conviction?
If he had asked her to send him photos claiming he was bob the photographer and paid her the money he promised then there wouldn't be any fraud from what I can see.
So has the fact he promised money and then turned it into blackmail become the basis for charging him with fraud by false representation?

Images have monetary value
Ask yourself, what is the monetary value of the images that were extracted from the victim by fraud or blackmail? Well, in this case: selling a nude to a customer can cost on average between 3 and 5 USD per picture and customer via platforms. Assuming the peron that extracted the images got about 20-50 under the pretense to build a portfolio, we are at a damage of 60 to 250 USD alone. Now, multiply that by the number of potential customers, and for sake of argument, let's say about 100, the damages are at 6000 to 25000, though some images can sell thousands or tenthousands of times. That money, or a portion of it, could have been defrauded from the victim by pretending to be a modeling agency.

Images are property
The maker of an image holds copyright in the images, which is a property interest. Whoever legally owns an image or the files that make an image owns property interest in them. It does not matter that an image file is not tangible, it's property under the definition of "any property" under Fraud Act 2006 §5(2).

(2)“Gain” and “loss”—
(a)extend only to gain or loss in money or other property;
(b)include any such gain or loss whether temporary or permanent;
and “property” means any property whether real or personal (including things in action and other intangible property).

The judge did not want to evaluate the monetary value of the images
The judge's language is quite clear in para 18, that he doesn't want to engage in evaluating the damage in money, as the victim is not in the market of selling her images online. Instead, he argues that the fraud impacted the dignity of her as a person and points to what in the us could be called "emotional distress and suffering" as part of the reasoning. The deprivation of property was proven as the required loss,  and the impact was chosen instead of the monetary amount to select the proper sentencing schedule.
In Para 19, taking this as high impact, the reviewing judge reasons to look at the enhanced categories of 4 instead of the no monetary loss category 5. Comparing to other offenses, the reasoning goes that 3 and 4 would be permissable, and eventually ends that the emotional and reputation damage to the victim puts it in category 3, table 1.
This enhancement is justified in para 20, where the judge points to the modus operandi of choosing vulnerable victims.

You could look at what money the victim could have made with a “fansonly” page. That would be a baseline for damages, even if she had no intention of doing that.

@gnasher729 oooor, the judge takes other estimations of damage, which they did.


the Defendant seemingly catfished the victim by pretending to be a modelling agency and various other personas

Simply put, he lied to his victim that he was a photographer and that he was a model agent (and some other people) to obtain intimate photos from her.
Fraud by false representation,  Section 2 Fraud Act 2006:

(1) A person is in breach of this section if he—
(a) dishonestly makes a false representation, and

He made a website falsely claiming to be a model agency website and he  falsely claimed he was a model agent.

(b) intends, by making the representation—
(i)to make a gain for himself or another, or ...

He lied to persuade his victim to make intimate photos of herself and send the photos to him.

(2) A representation is false if—
(a)it is untrue or misleading, and

He wasn't a model agent or photographer or the other fake people.

(b) the person making it knows that it is, or might be, untrue or misleading.

He knew he wasn't a model agent etc.

(3) “Representation” means any representation as to fact or law ...

Section 5(2) Fraud Act 2006:

... and property means any property whether real or personal (including things in action and other intangible property.

Explanatory notes for section 5:

Section 5 defines the meaning of “gain” and “loss” for the purposes of sections 2 to 4. The definitions are essentially the same as those in section 34(2)(a) of the Theft Act 1968 and section 32(2)(b) of the Theft Act (Northern Ireland) 1969. Under these definitions, “gain” and “loss” are limited to gain and loss in money or other property. The definition of “property” which applies in this context is based on section 4(1) of the Theft Act 1968 (read with section 34(1) of that Act) and section 4(1) of the Theft Act (Northern Ireland) 1969 (read with section 32(1) of that Act). The definition of “property” covers all forms of property, including intellectual property, although in practice intellectual property is rarely “gained” or “lost”.


but if you read fraud in that sense surely it means anyone lying to anyone else and being sent anything at all would be fraud. Someone simply lying about who they are and receiving nude images on the Internet has never been charged with fraud, there seem to have to be other factors, promising money then refusing to pay, blackmailing for more pictures or money, selling the pictures to other people etc.

@Cardgame482 The offence of section 2 fraud seems to be made out. What do you say is missing?

For it to be fraud in and of itself the false representation has to lead to a financial or physical property gain or loss. I understand he promised money and never sent it. My question is really is this the reason it was charged as fraud because if he had merely been using a fake persona online and someone had sent or even sold him photos then I've never seen that classed as fraud. If you see my meaning?

@Cardgame482 "any property whether real or personal (including things in action and other intangible property." - where does it say that it needs to be tangible? Images are property.

@Cardgame482 The law doesn't say the property must be "physical". It says "property means any property whether real or personal (including things in action and other intangible property."

But on that understanding no one has ever been charged with fraud by misrepresentation because they lied about who they are on the Internet and someone sent them a picture it being intimate or not is immaterial to the concept of property.

@Cardgame482 I don't understand your reply. People have been charged with section 2 fraud in relation to lying on the internet. You have asked a question about such a person. Again, what elements of the offence are missing from these circumstances?

Telling lies about yourself and receiving images does not seem by itself to constitute fraud. I have never seen anyone charged with fraud by misrepresentation solely on the basis that they lied about something and received pictures. Otherwise anyone who ever received a picture and told some sort of lie about themselves would be charged with fraud.

@Cardgame482 they solicited the pictures, which makes their lies fraud.

Does that make any instance of someone lying about themselves in any way and asking to see a picture of any type fraud? That would make the law incredibly vague and yet never used for that specific purpose hence why I thought it was odd here to drop the blackmail and pursue the fraud.

@Cardgame482 you repeat it's "never used for that purpose" - the judgment you ask about cites another case (R v Falder) in which the criminal was charged with and convicted of (among other things) several counts of fraud by representation for lying to girls and young women to get intimate images.

Another similar case is that of Elahi.
